# Update column with select from another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, and the situation is as following: One table keeps track of the employees of a company with, say at the simplest case only the id and a check YES or NO if the employee is in the building. The other table keeps track of all the events of employees leaving the building.

events table has 
ID || event_date

employee
ID || inside

The events table has multiple entries for the same employee because he has left the building multiple times.

I need to add a column to the employee table with leaving_date. 
So I did an inner join with the events table by taking the max of the events. The problem is that it does not take only the max entry. It takes multiple entries.

```
SELECT A.id, MAX (event_date) EVENT_DATE 
FROM employee A
INNER JOIN events B
ON A.id= B.id
WHERE    B.id= A.id

GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: "The problem is that it does not take only the max entry. It takes multiple entries." What do you mean by this? Some sample data and expected result would help to clarify what your intentions are because, as it stands, it is unclear what the problem is you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is compute the `leaving_date` inside a subquery, and then join this to the `employee` table:

```
SELECT A.id,
       COALESCE(B.leaving_date, SYSDATE) AS leaving_date      -- and maybe other columns
FROM employee A                                               -- from employee
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MAX(event_date) AS leaving_date
    FROM events
    GROUP BY id
) B
    ON A.id = B.id
```